# How to attach private vnet or subnet with container instances in java using Azure SDK?

Tags: java, azure-container-instances, azure-sdk, private-subnet

Challenge in attaching subnet and vnet configurations while creating azure container instances.

I am trying to create Azure container instances using the Azure SDK - Java/.Net. This container requires to communicate with components across different VMs. I was able to achieve this using Azure CLI commands with vnet and subnet configurations. But unable to replicate the same via SDK.

Code Snippet in Java

```
ContainerGroup containerGroup = azure.containerGroups().define(aciName).withRegion(Region.EUROPE_NORTH)
                    .withExistingResourceGroup(rgName).withLinux()
                    .withPrivateImageRegistry(registryServer, registryServerName, registryServerKey)
                    .defineVolume(volumeMountName).withExistingReadOnlyAzureFileShare(fileShareName)
                    .withStorageAccountName(storageAccountName).withStorageAccountKey(storageAccountKey).attach()
                    .defineContainerInstance(aciName).withImage(containerImageName).withExternalTcpPort(80)
                    .withVolumeMountSetting(volumeMountName, volumeMountPath).withCpuCoreCount(1)
                    .withMemorySizeInGB(1.5).withEnvironmentVariable("APP_PATH", volumeMountPath)
                    .withStartingCommandLine(commandLineArgs.toString()).attach().withDnsPrefix(aciName)
                    .withRestartPolicy(ContainerGroupRestartPolicy.NEVER).create();
```

Azure CLI

> az container create --resource-group  --name  --image
>    --cpu 1 --memory 1.5 --registry-login-server 
>   --registry-username  --registry-password  --azure-file-volume-share-name 
>   --azure-file-volume-account-name >  --azure-file-volume-account-key  --azure-file-volume-mount-path  --restart-policy Never --e  --subnet  --subnet-address-prefix  --vnet  --vnet-name  --subscription
>    --command-line ""

Unable to attach the vnet and subnet configurations while creating azure container instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that deploy ACI in Vnet is not supported in Java currently. You can take a look at the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-java/issues/741) in Github.

If you take a look at the CLI command which can achieve it, then you will find the command actually use the Azure REST API to do that.

[image]

In the request, it set the container group property `networkProfile` with the subnet network profile. So if you really want to deploy the ACI in the Vnet, you could use the [Azure REST API for Container Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/containergroups/createorupdate) to achieve it in the Java code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. Is this option available with .Net?

Comment: @ArchanaAshwin I just describe it for Java. But for ACI, all the language use the Azure REST API. So it's also available in .NET.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Tried using the Azure REST API and it works.

Comment: @ArchanaAshwin What's the reason you did not mark the answer when it helps you?

Comment: Thanks for the help Charles. Facing difficulty in generating the access token for consuming the Azure Rest API to create a container group. Let me know for any pointers.

Comment: @ArchanaAshwin You can take a look at [Service to service calls using client credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). Or you just see the [Azure REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/).

Comment: The references given above are very helpful. Thank you.